# passing an NSMutableArray to an other View

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray

my problem is this I fill my Array in my rootView and want to pass this Array to the mainView View.

I tryed it this way:

```
mvController = [[mainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

mvController.listOfContent == self.listOfContent;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvController animated:YES];
mvController = nil;

[mvController release];
```

did I missed some thing?

Comment: mvController.listOfContent == self.listOfContent; should be mvController.listOfContent = self.listOfContent; (one equals sign).

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it's correct, except because of the "release", that must be before "mvController = nil" (otherwise, you will be releasing "nil").

You must be more specific with your error, but probably the mistake regards using "listOfContent" inside viewDidLoad or init.

Comment: hello eduardo, the error is when i buld the Array in my rootViewController it hass all the entrys when I pass it to the mainView it is null. In the mainView I import the rootViewController.h I init the Array in the viewDidLoad.....

Comment: small question: is mainView.listOfContents a "retain"able property?

Comment: yes it is "retain"able `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfContent;`

Comment: And in rootViewController? Is it a variable or a retainable property?

Comment: it is the same for the rootViewController....
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfContent;`

Comment: for some reasons I suffer really heavy problems (more than usual) with XCode I did't change anything but now it works!?!

Comment: are you using LOC on mainView's viewDidLoad or viewWill/DidAppear?

Comment: new day same problem last night it works to day nothing....
@Eduardo i'm not sure what you mean. I pass the array when I push the view and in the View where it should arrive is the array is empty.

Comment: my doubt is if "mainView.loc = self.loc" is called before or after you are using "loc". When I started using XIBs, I had some problems understanding the order of messages (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, push, etc). Oh, and if it worked without code changing, you have a race condition (most probably you are calling UI-code outside UI-thread)